# how to send a receive array value to another model in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
  public function user_delete($email){
    //echo $email;
    $this->load->model('hradvalid');
    $user_id = $this->hradvalid->user_id($email);
     $user_email=$user_id[0]->email;
    $this->hradvalid->user_delete($email,$user_email); 
     if($this->hradvalid->user_delete()){
        $this->session->set_flashdata("alert","your data deleted successfully");
     }else{
      $this->session->set_flashdata("alert","error comming sorry!");
     }
     return redirect('admin/dashboard');

}

     model code
         public function user_id($value)
     {
    $q = $this->db->select('email')
                      ->from('user')
                      ->where('id',$value)
                      ->get();

    return $q->result();            

  }
   public function user_delete($value,$email)
   {
    $user_delete=$this->db->delete('user',array('id'=>$value));
    $user_delete=$this->db->delete('acuser',array('username'=>$email));

    return $user_delete;
}
```

above code is my controller I receive a value from `hradvaild model` and method `user_id` getting one value this is working now I want to send this value to `hradvaild` model in `user_delete` method  here I am getting an error `offset[0]` error  please help me  and also `$user_email` undefined

Comment: Show the model code of `user_id($email)` and `user_delete($email,$user_email)`

Comment: yes  you are right

Comment: code is working fine just send `$user_email` value how to do this

Comment: Without model code I cant help you

Comment: You want to completely delete the data??

Comment: yes I want to delete

Comment: Check answer below. All code is Changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

**In Controller**

```
public function user_delete($email)
{
    $this->load->model('hradvalid');
    $user_id = $this->hradvalid->user_id($email);
    $user_email = $user_id[0]['email'];

    if(!$this->hradvalid->user_delete($email,$user_email)){ # Changed
        $this->session->set_flashdata("alert","error comming sorry!");  # Changed
    }else{
        $this->session->set_flashdata("alert","your data deleted successfully");  # Changed
    }
    return redirect('admin/dashboard');

}
```

**In Model**

```
public function user_id($value)
{
    $query = $this->db->select('email')
        ->from('user')
        ->where('id',$value)
        ->get();

    return $query->result_array(); # Change this     

}

public function user_delete($value,$email)
{
    $user_delete=$this->db->delete('user',array('id'=>$value));
    $user_delete=$this->db->delete('acuser',array('username'=>$email));
}
```

Comment: @ajeetsingh Happy to help :)